# Define a number format in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, currency-formatting

i am struggling to define a number format for a cell on google spreadsheets. I want to just add the number format for the currency € Euro, so that i receive the following separator in the following case:

200.000,00€

I couldn't manage it until now i always got back the english separating way of this number.

Comment: I thought excel and google spreadsheets is somehow related. Some excel experts might solve also number format defining problems in something similar as google spreadsheets. That´s why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile doesn't say where you are, but you can go to File | Spreadsheet Settings | Locale and change it to (say) Germany. Note that this will change the settings for all decimal numbers, currency values and dates across the spreadsheet though.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the answer. Sometimes the solution is as easy as this!